# How to resize the x-axis and make it different from the y-axis Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, elementtree, subplot

I have the following development that I am working on with ElementTree, Pandas and Matplotlib modules in Python:

```
    def extract_name_value(signals_df):
        #print(signals_df)
        names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
        num_names_list = len(names_list)

        colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']

        # Creation Graphic
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 20))
        plt.suptitle(f'File PXML: {rootXML}', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', position=(0.75, 0.90))
        fig.tight_layout()
        i = 1
        for name in names_list:
            # get data
            data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
            datax = signals_df["Name"]
            # x = [n for n in range(len(data))]
            x = [n for n in range(len(datax))]
            print(x)
            # get color
            j = random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
            # add subplots
            ax = plt.subplot(num_names_list, 1, i)
            ax.plot(x, data, drawstyle='steps', marker='o', color=colors[j], linewidth=3)
            # plt.xticks(None)
            ax.set_ylabel(name, fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=50, labelpad=45)
            ax.grid(alpha=0.4)
            i += 1

        plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:
[image: Error Image]

I have been looking for the error and I totally understand that the dimensions of x and y must be equal, but there is the possibility of making a graph where the x-axis is greater than the y-axis? and also the x-axis comes from a variable not related to the y-axis? how would this be?

The x-axis is the count of all the values it has in the Signal element of the xml file: [I put it here because of how extensive it is](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/example.xml) and this value is larger than the y-axis, but how to contemplate the 3 values that I bring from the xml that are Singal Name, Signal Value as y-axis and Count of Signals as x-axis. I really appreciate your comments and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to plot several stepped values agains their order of appearance (X-index) in XML file. Then you should plot against original dataframe's X values. I haven't changed your code much for style or such, just fixed a little.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

file_xml = 'example_un_child4.xml'

def transfor_data_atri(rootXML):
    file_xml = ET.parse(rootXML)
    data_XML = [
        {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
         "Value": int(signal.attrib["Value"].split(' ')[0])
         } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
    ]
    
    signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data_XML)
    extract_name_value(signals_df)
    
def extract_name_value(signals_df):
    #print(signals_df)
    names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
    num_names_list = len(names_list)

    colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']

    # Creation Graphic
    #fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 20), sharex=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=num_names_list, figsize=(10, 15), sharex=True)
    plt.suptitle(f'File PXML: {file_xml}', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', position=(0.75, 0.90))
    #fig.tight_layout()
    i = 1
    for pos, name in enumerate(names_list):
        # get data
        data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
        datax = signals_df["Name"]
        # x = [n for n in range(len(data))]
        #x = [n for n in range(len(datax))]
        #print(x)
        # get color
        j = random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
        # add subplots
        #ax[pos] = plt.subplot(num_names_list, 1, i)
        ax[pos].plot(data.index, data, drawstyle='steps', marker='o', color=colors[j], linewidth=3)
        # plt.xticks(None)
        ax[pos].set_ylabel(name, fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=50, labelpad=45)
        ax[pos].grid(alpha=0.4)
        i += 1
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

transfor_data_atri(file_xml)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, your correction to the code has worked well for me, so it was only to include the index inside the dataframe and contemplate it inside the for. @crayxt Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, a question… What does IIUC mean?

Comment: @MarshRangel it stands for `If I understand correctly`. You were close to the solution in your code, just needed a little fix. This site helped me many times, I just returning a bit from it. If not I, someone would have helped you anyways!